# SSH stops at 'SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received'

Tags: snow-leopard, ssh

When I attempt to SSH to anything from my iMac (SSH, git, etc.), SSH freezes at `debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received`. This only happens on my account; I created a new account as a test and everything worked fine. I did [reinstall SSH](http://openssh.org/portable.html), but both accounts use the same executable. I can SSH to my computer from other computers, so I'm assuming that the problem lies with ssh and not with sshd.

SSH version: `OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011`
OS X Version: `Version 10.6.8 build 10K549`
Log: http://pastebin.com/wrugsYhf  (I use a custom port, 7742)

Is there anything I can do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in Terminal worked for me, though I'm currently unsure why. One thing I did not mention in the body of my question was that I had to modify `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist` in order to get sshd to work: [here's](http://pastebin.com/nqD1UV7B) a link to my `org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist` in case anyone in the future thinks they know what caused the problem.

Comment: Your link to the plist is broken (Sept. 20, 2015)

Comment: This worked for me on Windows when Git SSH operations in PowerShell were hanging, but when using Git-Bash. You'll need to do `rm env:\SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, then subsequent SSH operations in that session will work. It doesn't seem to write a new value to `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` so this fix isn't permanent and I'll need to figure out what's setting that.

Interestingly, the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` var ended with a different pid than the `SSH_AGENT_PID` value. I'm guessing at that for the reason for failure.